# ssh-agent ssh-add ok in user not in sudo

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I created an SSH-Agent to provide my key to the ssh/scp cmd when connecting to my server.
I also scripted a SSH-Add with the command 'expect' to write my paraphrase when it's needed.

This works perfectly with my user "user".

But I'm executing a python script that uses /dev/mem that need to be run as root through sudo. This python script call another bash script with ssh and scp cmd inside.
Therefore all these cmd are executed as root and my agent/ssh-add doesn't work anymore, keeping asking for the paraphrase for each file.

How could I fix that ? I don't want to log as root and run a agent as root.
I tried the sudo -u user ssh but it doesn't work (ie: need to enter my paraphrase)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Mat

EDIT: my code:
The py script needing the sudo

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
from datetime import datetime
import picamera
import os
import sys
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
# GPIO 23 set up as input. It is pulled up to stop false signals
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

#set path and time to create the folder where the images will be saved
pathtoscript = "/home/pi/python-scripts"

current_time = time.localtime()[0:6]
dirfmt = "%4d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d-%02d"
dirpath = os.path.join(pathtoscript , dirfmt)
localdirname = dirpath % current_time[0:6] #dirname created with date and time
remotedirname = dirfmt % current_time[0:6] #remote-dirname created with date and time
os.mkdir(localdirname) #mkdir
pictureName = localdirname + "/image%02d.jpg" #path+name of pictures
var = 1
while var == 1:
    try:
            GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)
            with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
                    #camera.capture_sequence(["/home/pi/python-scripts/'dirname'/image%02d.jpg" % i for i in range(2)])
                    camera.capture_sequence([pictureName % i for i in range(19)])
                    camera.close()
                    cmd = '/home/pi/python-scripts/picturesToServer {0}  &'.format(remotedirname)
                    call ([cmd], shell=True)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            GPIO.cleanup()       # clean up GPIO on CTRL+C exit
GPIO.cleanup()           # clean up GPIO on normal exit
```

---

the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
ssh user@server mkdir /home/repulsion/picsToAnimate/"$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
ssh user@server cp "$1"/* /home/repulsion/picsToAnimate/"$1"/ >/dev/null 2>&1
for i in $( ls ); do
    scp $i user@server:/home/repulsion/picsToAnimate/"$1"/  >/dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Comment: can you share your code? How are you trying to call a `bash` script?

Comment: just edited with my code. I could execute the bash script as a cron every minute or so as user... is there something better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the SSH agent environment variables to be passed in through the sudo.

To do so, you can run `sudo -E` to pass all environment variables in through sudo; but this can be dangerous, so it's probably better to pass just the ones you need. The easiest way to do this is for `sudo` to invoke `env` to invoke the given program with the appropriate environment variables set:

```
$ sudo env SSH_AGENT_PID=$SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK my-script
```

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables needed for shh-agent are removed by sudo.  see [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/107187/ssh-agent-forwarding-and-sudo-to-another-user) for how to keep them.

But why do you have a ssh-add there type the passphrase for you insted of just having a ssh key with no passphrase? You can remove it with

```
ssh-keygen -p [-P old_passphrase] [-N new_passphrase] [-f keyfile]
```

Comment: you're right! I felt it was more secure to have a paraphrase, but anyway, all this doesn't look really secure, does it ?

Comment: @matthieumatthieu It is generally more secure to have a passphrase on the file, and then use something like [keychain](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keychain) to automatically prompt you and set up the SSH agent when you log in. That way, if you throw out your drive or something of the sort, someone can't extract the passwordless key; the key is only vulnerably while the SSH agent is actually running. Using `expect` to provide the password is not really secure, because then the password and key are both present on the same disk at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i didn't know the 'keychain' stuff. But i'm doing an automate that will have no keyboard or user interaction except to push a button... So I can't even write once the paraphrase. Understood for expect, maybe i'll go for a paraphrase less option or cron :(